# How do I force push local project folder (updated) to remote branch of same folder but slightly outdated?

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I am using Eclipse with eGit plugin, my problem is: I had to work in college today on project without git (Downloaded as project from Bitbucket), worked on it, did quite a lot of updates, about 600 new lines in different files so manual merging would be very bad. So I have right now an offline version (the newer one) and I have online branch version which is older. How can I force update online version with offline version?

Comment: What is your environment? Is it a unix-based system (like Linux)? I don't know if you can do this easily, you could try to make a patch from your changes using the _diff_ command, then apply it to your copy of the repository (the one that you use with eclipse) and commit from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply zip your offline project, unzip it on a local working tree that you would empty first .

Git will detect all the changes, all the added or removed files.
Simply:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "new commit"
git push.
```

You publish (push) a new commit which will represent all your changes.
No merge required here.